# How can I make my primary partition larger?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, resize

Well I'm running 2 different distro's of Linux right now and I decided to make my Ubuntu partition my primary partition larger so I took 119.53 GB out of my other distro's partition and it became unallocated and then I figured Gparted would when I right click on it to resize/move give me the option of using it to make another partition bigger but it did not so I went Google searching on line and in one post I saw it said you had to format the unallocated space so I formatted it to ext4 the same as my primary partition but still no options to add it to any thing what do I do?

*UPDATE: I have included a picture my Ubuntu primary partition is highlighted which is the one I want to make larger the partition labeled extra is what I want to use to enlarge my primary partition.

[image]

Comment: Also i'm trying to resize it from my other linux os.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/144809/can-i-resize-my-partitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to use [gparted live](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php/livecd.php) or boot your ubuntu live disc and install gparted to resize the partition, so that no partitions are mounted whilst you are working on them.

Comment: Alternatively just use a Ubuntu Live CD/USB drive. Gparted is installed by default on there.

Comment: So if I boot into an ubuntu live cd and use gparted it will give me the option to make my primary partition larger?

Comment: That is correct, let me know how you get on. :o)

Comment: I'll do it in about 45mins because I have to finish a download which is going to take that long then I will pop in my ubuntu cd and give it a shot I will tell you if it worked or not.

Comment: Just looked at the picture you added, and from what I can see it may not work as you need to resize from the next partition along. So you may need to merge sda6 and sd8 (and the unallocated space between them), then resize sda6 making space at the beginning / preceeding the partition, before increasing sda1.

Comment: I decided top just format my entire hard drive and start anew because this has just become a big mess see here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/159601/how-do-i-format-my-entire-hdd thank you though I will still accept your answer.