# How do I format my entire HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, drive, format

Ok I have recently made some mistakes with installing some operating systems that I should have just kept on a live cd not ubuntu but another os and with my ocd when I saw my lot's of different partitions I just wanted to reset my computer so it boot's up and doesn't load any os and I have to put in my ubuntu live cd and install that and that would be my only os on this computer so I want to know how I can just wipe my entire hard drive so when it boot's I get to put my live cd in and start anew?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Get your Ubuntu Live CD
- Put it in your drive and boot up from CD
- Choose wipe and install Ubuntu
- That will format the whole hard drive and clean everything of it
- Then Ubuntu will install and be the only OS on your disk

Follow those steps and you will be able to wipe everything and reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu live cd will do that for you, after selecting 'install ubuntu' choose 'erase entire disk and install ubuntu' and that will erase the entire disk and install ubuntu.

The other option is to boot the ubuntu live disc, select 'try ubuntu' and then open 'disc utility' and format / partition the drive.