# Installed Ubuntu 13.04, but PC still tries to boot Windows 7

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 13.04 on my PC. In the installation I chose the option to only install Ubuntu and delete Windows 7 completely. When I reboot after the installation is complete, it tries to boot Windows 7 with the following error:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  Status: 0xc000000f

  Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

Here's my `fdisk` log file:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000218b6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   216518655   108258304   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       216520702   250068991    16774145    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       216520704   250068991    16774144   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xa5ae9d9c

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048  3907026943  1953512448    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I'm new to Linux and appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: give your fdisk log details.

Comment: Looks like ubuntu didn't install successfully, otherwise you would have been provided with a grub menu, which would allow you to select from multiple operating systems installed and stuff like memtest

Comment: @3bu1 tell me how to do it, and i will gladly show you my fdisk log

Comment: @JohnMerlino i tried to install ubuntu like 3 times to today... was always "succesfull" but had always that error after reboot.

Comment: Open Terminal **Ctrl + Alt + T** then type in `sudo fdisk -l>~/Desktop/logfile.txt` a file will appear on your desktop, open the file, select all the text and add it to the bottom of your Question as an edit.

Comment: If you can not get to your Ubuntu Desktop, because you do not have the option, press the **Ctrl** key as you start the computer and you may get a menu displayed to select Ubuntu.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/106873/how-to-use-fdisk-to-manage-partitions-on-linux/ go through this link for fdisk log

Comment: @user164393 What media did you use to install Ubuntu, CD or USB?

Comment: @kingmilo installed it with a cd

Comment: @user164393 When you do the installation you will need to format the entire HDD by choosing `erase entire disk and install ubuntu`, it doesn't look like you have formatted the entire HDD hence the hassles with booting into Ubuntu. Have a look at this thread for help - http://askubuntu.com/questions/159601/how-do-i-format-my-entire-hdd

Comment: @kingmilo that's exactly how i installed ubuntu. still got that error

Comment: @user164393 You seem to have two HDD's in your computer, `/dev/sda` (128 GB) and `/dev/sdb` (2 TB). Windows looks like it is living on `/dev/sdb` and I believe your issue may be your boot loader. Which HDD do you want to install Ubuntu on? I would recommend in your case removing the HDD you are not going to use for now, and trying to do the install again with only 1 HDD in your computer. Once you have done the install successfully then you can go ahead and put the other HDD back into your computer and do what you please with it.

Comment: @kingmilo so basically i install ubuntu with the hdd out. after the installation i put the hdd back in and that should do it. im going to try that out immediately.

Comment: @user164393 Correct, remove one of the HDD's (decide which one you want to use for Ubuntu and remove the other one), then go through the install again. Once you finish the installation and you can boot into/ use Ubuntu then you can decide if you would like to put the other HDD back into the computer. I think having 2 HDD's in the computer during the install is confusing you when you go through the install options so let's try it this way. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run [Boot-Repair](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair)'s `Recommended Repair`. Write the URL on a paper.
2. Make your `BIOS` boot on the Windows disk (2TB)
3. Reboot the PC. You should see a (GRUB) menu with access to both Ubuntu and Windows. If any problem, indicate the URL.