# Problem with free space at home directory

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

I used Windowns until september 2012. Then I downloaded Ubuntu on my computer and since then I always use it.

But recently I'm facing problems with space when I'm about to upgrade some packages.
But to deal with this I could simply do an `autoclean` command. The great problem started when I downloaded the computer algebra system GAP (http://www.gap-system.org/) and when I tried to install it, the installation process was suspended because there was no more free space.

So I decided to look at the specifications of my home directory, and I was almost out of free space. After I removed some useless files, I tried to install it again but the same problem ocurred.

The free space of my home directory is now 986,3 MB and the free space of my host directory (wich is, I suppose, the directory of my Windows stuff) is 216,9 GB.

I would like to know if there is some way to somehow move the free space of the host directory to the home one. I found a question ([Unallocated space, how to resize /home partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143513/unallocated-space-how-to-resize-home-partition)) that is similiar with this but I'm not sure, so I thought that asking here before would be better.

I would also like to emphasize that I'm a complete noob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably perform a real install. Wubi is no longer recommended and was primarily intended as a way to try Ubuntu more throughly than a live-cd could.

However, if you do want to keep your Wubi install and just resize, you can find the instructions and software here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk