# How to allocate more disk space to ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I am currently dual booting with windows and ubuntu. As ubuntu is running out of space, I want to give more disk space to ubuntu. I tried resizing `/dev/sda5`, but I am not able to do it. Please help me out!

[image]

Comment: In order to increase the size of sda5 you need have available space under sda3 as sda5 is a sub partition of sda3 which you currently dont have. This can be done by reducing another sub partition e.g. sda7 by 20Gb and then increasing sda5 by 20Gb.

Comment: I tried resizing sda7 but i am not able to cick the "resize" option. Why it is so? Why it is not shown?

Comment: first try to reduce the size of the other partitions... only then you can increase the size of the desired partitions

Comment: Also I will suggest you to take important backups. before making any changes to disks

Comment: Have a look at the following post http://askubuntu.com/q/143513/288011 this is what I think you are looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

*To resize `/dev/sda5` open `GParted` and follow these steps carefully:*

**1. Unmount `/dev/sda7`.**

Unmount `/home` patition at `/dev/sda7` by right click then click on `umount` option. If any error occurs use this command to unmount.

```
sudo umount -lv "/home"
```

unmounting will dissappear `lock key simbol`.

**1. Make some free space.**

To make some free space right click on `/dev/sda7` and click on `Resize/Move` option and resize the partition. It will make some `unallocated` space.

**2. Unmount `/dev/sda5`**

To resize `/dev/sda5` partition first you have to `unmount` the `/dev/sda5` partitoin to be able to make changes. unmount using step 1.

**3. Resize `/dev/sda5`**

To resize `/dev/sda5` right click on `/dev/sda5` and click on `Resize/Move` option and resize according to your need.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am also new to Ubuntu system and also had the same problem few days ago.

- Boot from live USB drive i.e. make your pen drive boot-able from any version of Ubuntu using software or commands from windows.
- Then go to you boot menu, i.e. restart your PC and enter to boot option.
- Your USB drive's name will be there (at bottom, most probably) select that option.
- New screen will appear select `try mode`.
- Now, don't install just boot it. Some programs will come pre-installed.
- Open `Gparted`.
- Now, you can very easily resize the partition you want.

**Why can't you resize now.**
As you can clearly see, there is a `key` marked after each partitions name. *That means* **Those partitions are currently in use and you can't resize the partition currently in use**.

**What difference will create in `try mode`**

There will not be any drive in use as you have not booted your system from any operating system which is in partition itself.

 Hope that helps, Peace.