# How to Initialize 4TB in Windows

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I built a PC for a client but I forgot to partition/format the 4TB storage drive in Windows before installing Ubuntu. It's set up like this:

- SSD: Windows OS + Ubuntu OS & Swap File
- 4TB HDD: Ubuntu Home Directory (3TB Dedicated)

So, Windows cannot use the 4TB right now. Is there a way to use the remaining 1TB in Windows without having to reinstall Ubuntu and potentially Windows too?

EDIT: Perhaps split the 4TB into two partitions, 3TB and 1TB (for WIN)? Is this possible in Ubuntu without losing data?

Comment: Can you run Ubuntu and give as the output of "sudo blkid -o list". I want to see the partitions.

Comment: I'm not with the PC right now, but I can later. The 4TB in question should only have one partition (3TB) for /home and 1TB free, but Win10 can't use it, just says unallocated

Comment: @AlexRobinson create a new partition in Windows in that unallocated space then :)

Comment: Ok, so it should be no problem. Just run Ubuntu and use "gparted". There you can see the drives and the partitions. If there is some free space (unallocated) you can create a new partition in NTFS format. Ok, maybe you are not able to create a new partition if you are using Legacy/BIOS instead of UEFI (Legacy/BIOS has limitation to 4 partitions... I should mentioned that extended partitions are also possible).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions) and [Unallocated space, how to resize /home partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143513/)